# Specify bearer for TCP connection in Android 6/7

Tags: android, tcp, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

Is it possible, for an app on a modern Android phone to specifiy which bearer a TCP connection should be made on?

i.e. I would like to open a connection to a server using Wifi *and* a connection to a (possibly different) server using GPRS.

I'm guessing that I would need to enumerate the interfaces on the phone and specify source addresses for the connections, as well as destination ports and addresses.

Is there a way of using "SO_BINDTODEVICE" in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, but as of Lollipop, there are dedicated Android API's for doing what you want.

You can use the [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworks()) to enumerate the available networks, and then [obtain a SocketFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#getSocketFactory()) whose sockets will only communicate over the selected network.

Answer (score 0):

TCP does not worry about the medium of communication. Its agnostic to internal mechanisms of the IP and Ethernet layer. So, I think, TCP won't help you to differentiate between GPRS and Wifi.

You can bind to a specific IP address available in the system. The IP can be the src in any particular medium.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is a little too high-level.  In non-Android Linux you *can* specify that a TCP connection be bound to a particular device, using SO_BINDTODEVICE.